# .NET 8 / WCF - The value of this argument must be positive. (Parameter 'size')

Tags: wcf, .net-core, .net-8.0

After updating from .NET 6/7 to .NET 8, we get this exception when trying to invoke a call to a WCF endpoint using nettcp binding.

```
The value of this argument must be positive. (Parameter 'size')
Actual value was 0.
```

````
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUtilities.ValidateBufferBounds(Int32 bufferSize, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.BeginRead(Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveHandshakeFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgradeAsync(Stream stream, OutWrapper`1 remoteSecurityWrapper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgradeAsync(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgradeAsync(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, OutWrapper`1 connectionWrapper, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreambleAsync(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpenAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnOpenAsyncInternal(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.System.ServiceModel.IAsyncCommunicationObject.OpenAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpenAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnOpenAsyncInternal(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.System.ServiceModel.IAsyncCommunicationObject.OpenAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncInternal(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletion(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to explicitly add references to `System.ServiceModel.*` packages to csproj.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="6.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="6.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.0" />
```

This pattern repeated across any solution that was upgraded.
One *.sln gave a further error like

```
Identity check failed for outgoing message. The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was 'local.system-name' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim           'local.system-name'. 
If this is a legitimate remote endpoint, you can fix the problem by explicitly specifying DNS identity 'local.system-name' as the Identity property of EndpointAddress when creating channel proxy.
```

Yes...it was reporting the same DNS as expected and received. Fixed with adding this too

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="6.2.0" />
```